# Run two different jobs depending upon the start and end time

Tags: python, datetime

- I am trying to implement a simple schedule in python3.6. Given two time start and end time. It will execute the respective job.
- All the time will be in 24hrs clock. Execute JobA if the current time falls between JobA start and end time. Execute JobB if the current time falls between JobB start and end time.
- JobA start time is 09:00:00 and JobA end time is 17:55:00.
- JobB start time is 18:00:00 and JobB end time is 08:55:00.
- The issue is I can make it work if this is the only case, if the start and end time for JobA and JobB changes then I am unable to serve the use-case.
- Is there a better way through which I can serve the use-case and execute the respective activity depending upon the start and end time.
- The code I tried, in the below code I am getting 'Both jobs are currently offline.'

```
import datetime
import pytz

# Define the start and end times of Job A and Job B in the format (hh:mm:ss)
job_a_start = '09:00:00'
job_a_end = '17:55:00'
job_b_start = '18:00:00'
job_b_end = '08:55:00'

# Define the IST timezone
ist_tz = pytz.timezone('Asia/Kolkata')

# Get the current time in IST
now_ist = datetime.datetime.now(ist_tz).time()

# Convert job start and end times to datetime objects
job_a_start_dt = datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date.today(), datetime.datetime.strptime(job_a_start, '%H:%M:%S').time())
job_a_end_dt = datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date.today(), datetime.datetime.strptime(job_a_end, '%H:%M:%S').time())
job_b_start_dt = datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date.today(), datetime.datetime.strptime(job_b_start, '%H:%M:%S').time())
job_b_end_dt = datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date.today(), datetime.datetime.strptime(job_b_end, '%H:%M:%S').time())

# Check which job is currently active
if job_a_start_dt.time() <= now_ist < job_a_end_dt.time():
    print("Job A is currently active.")
elif job_b_start_dt.time() <= now_ist < job_b_end_dt.time():
    print("Job B is currently active.")
elif now_ist < job_a_start_dt.time():
    time_diff = job_a_start_dt - datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date.today(), now_ist)
    print(f"Next job (Job A) starts in {time_diff}.")
elif now_ist < job_b_start_dt.time():
    time_diff = job_b_start_dt - datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date.today(), now_ist)
    print(f"Next job (Job B) starts in {time_diff}.")
else:
    print("Both jobs are currently offline.")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- After some brain storming, I can up with the below code. Which seems to be working for all the test-cases.
- Code

```
import datetime
import pytz


def is_time_between(start_time, end_time, check_time):
    fmt = '%H:%M:%S'

    # Convert strings to time objects
    start_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(start_time, fmt).time()
    end_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(end_time, fmt).time()
    check_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(check_time, fmt).time()

    # Set timezone to IST
    tz = pytz.timezone('Asia/Kolkata')

    # Convert times to datetime objects with today's date
    now = datetime.datetime.now(tz)
    start_datetime = tz.localize(datetime.datetime.combine(now.date(), start_time))
    end_datetime = tz.localize(datetime.datetime.combine(now.date(), end_time))

    # If end time is less than start time, assume it's on the next day
    if end_datetime <= start_datetime:
        end_datetime += datetime.timedelta(days=1)

    # Compare times
    return start_datetime <= tz.localize(datetime.datetime.combine(now.date(), check_time)) <= end_datetime


# Example usage
current_time = datetime.datetime.now(pytz.timezone('Asia/Kolkata')).strftime('%H:%M:%S')
job_a = is_time_between('01:00:00', '03:55:00', current_time)
job_b = is_time_between('03:55:00', '20:55:00', current_time)
if job_a:
    print('Job A')
elif job_b:
    print('Job B')
else:
    print('Neither')
```